# declare static variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, static

```
 var i=0;
 function mul()
 {
    var qty = document.getElementsByClassName("qty");
    var rs = document.getElementsByClassName("rs");
    var amt = document.getElementsByClassName("amt");
    var mul=(qty[i].value)*(rs[i].value);
    amt[i].setAttribute("value",mul);
   sp.appendChild(iteminp);
   sp.appendChild(qtyinp);
   sp.appendChild(rsinp);
   sp.appendChild(amtinp);
   i++;
}
```

In the above program i want the value of 'i' should be increased for each time we call the function and it should be same all over the program like static variable.
how to do it?

Comment: Whats the issue?

Comment: Exactly that way. It's global, so every function will see the same `i`.

Comment: just drop the `var` before `i `. Then `i` would be a global variable

Comment: There's nowhere there for `i` to be considered static. Do you simply want a global variable?  If yes then declare it as `window._i = 1;`, but this seems like a bad way to achieve something.  (It's common practice to prefix global vars with an underscore, and certainly don't just call it `i`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS variables are local to a function or they are global. Since you declared `i` outside a function, it's global.

To prove this, save this as test.html, open it in your browser and press the button a few times. I simplified your function a bit!

```
<script>
var i=0
function mul(){
  alert("i: " + i++)
}
</script>
<button onclick='mul()'>Press me</button>
```

Comment: no , you see the above code in that i did like that but, for the second time if i call the function it is showing a error that " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined "

Comment: I think that error message is coming from this line: `(qty[i].value)*(rs[i].value)` - if `qty[i]` or `rs[i]` don't evaluate to something (because `qty` or `rs` has nothing at element `i`) then you will get that error. So I think that the problem is not related to `i` being global.

Comment: yeah, you are right the error is in that line, but what is the problem ?

Comment: when i run it for first time it is successfully executed but for the second time it is showing like that,but for the second time i am supplying a value,but i don't know why it is showing like that an how to solve it. can you please help to solve this?

Comment: can you give your num to contact?

Comment: Suppose that `document.getElementsByClassName("qty")` finds two elements. Then your JS variable `qty` contains two things: `qty[0]` and `qty[1]`. If `i` is `3` then what will `qty[i]` return? Nothing (or `undefined`). So `qty[i].value` would be the same as `undefined.value` which throws an `TypeError`.

Comment: thank you very much dude,you are right, finally I solved with your help !!!!!!!!!!.Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can have a javascript file named globals.js(don't forget to include it in your index.html) then declare your global variable, which will be available in all your web solution.

***globals.js:***

```
var _i = 0; // Would not recomend using "i" as the variable name since it 
            // can polute the global scope
```

***yourFile.js:***

```
 function mul()
 {
   var qty = document.getElementsByClassName("qty");
   var rs = document.getElementsByClassName("rs");
   var amt = document.getElementsByClassName("amt");
   var mul=(qty[_i].value)*(rs[_i].value);
   amt[_i].setAttribute("value",mul);
   sp.appendChild(iteminp);
   sp.appendChild(qtyinp);
   sp.appendChild(rsinp);
   sp.appendChild(amtinp);
   _i++;
}
```

Comment: its like the same,its not working.can you please tell me any other way to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a decorator function that can wrap your function with a counter that will give you access to the count through a read only property.

This solution will require modern browsers due to having used `Symbol`, but you could substitute this with a dunder property eg. `__count__` in it's place.

```js
// this is used to create a privaty property on your function
const COUNT = typeof Symbol !== 'undefined' ? Symbol('count') : '__count__'

// this function takes your function and wraps it with a counter
function counter(fn) {
  // this is called whenever you call the decorated function
  function _counter(...args) {
    // increment the counter
    _counter[COUNT]++
    // call the original function
    return fn(...args)
  }
  // create the private property on your function and the accessor
  Object.defineProperties(_counter, {
    [COUNT]: { value: 0, writable: true },
    name: { value: fn.name || 'counter' },
    count: { get: () => _counter[COUNT] }
  })
  // return the decorator function
  return _counter
}

// function to decorate
function _mul(x, y) {
  // do something to multiply
  return x * y
}

// decorate your functions with the counter
const mul = counter(_mul)
const mul2 = counter(_mul)

// proof that both counters are independent and work correctly
console.log(
  mul(1, 2), // 2
  mul(3, 4), // 12
  `mul has been called ${mul.count} times`
)
console.log(
  mul2(5, 6), // 30
  mul2(7, 8), // 56
  mul2(9, 10),// 90
  `mul2 has been called ${mul2.count} times`
)
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/KyQQmL.js"></script>
```

Comment: i can't understand this , can you please suggest me a edit in my above program

Comment: can you give you  mobile number to contact?

Comment: Hi, sorry I did not reply. The function I provided wraps your function. it will attach a counter property to it that you can access using `mul.count` when you need to know how many times it had been called. This is the best solution because you are not polluting the global namespace with a variable. especially the use of `i` will bite you later as that is used in `for` loops by convention.